# Website not loading in WebView (javascript issue maybe)

Tags: android, webview, web

:)
So i'm trying to design an app, and i'm facing a problem i can't find the solution of..

Basically, i designed a Browser app, to load one particular website --> http://www.medishala.org/moonstone13/ 
But instead of loading the whole page, its giving me only the left corner logo and nothing else..
Other websites are loading fine, facing this problem in only this one. Can anyone please help me out?? 
The issue might be that the javascript is not compatible with android... Can anybody suggest a way around it??
Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

i think JavaScript is disabled in a WebView by Default.

Try to enable it:

```
//set JavaScript enabled
mywebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code I used and got the complete website. Here is the code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    setContentView(R.layout.placement_layout);
    showResults();
}

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
private void showResults() {
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS,
            Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.MyWebview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    String url = "http://www.medishala.org/moonstone13/";
    Log.d("Link", url);
    mWebView.loadUrl(url);
    final Activity MyActivity = this;
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            MyActivity.setTitle("Loading...");
            MyActivity.setProgress(progress * 100);
            if (progress == 100)
                MyActivity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        }
    });
}

protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
```

Comment: I tried this... but still loading only that logo image... not loading the full webpage...

Comment: @user2157303: I tried in my browser whatever I am getting the same page I got in `webview`. It took a lot of time to load the webpage. May be you have embedded much graphics in it.